# .NET 6.0 Windows Control Library No Longer Appears in Toolbox of Winforms Project since 17.3

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2022, toolbox, control-library

As of the latest release a solution containing a windows form project no longer shows a windows forms control library in the same solution in the ToolBox.

Here is a sample of the problem. It's a solution with two projects, one is a windows Form Project (called "DemoApp") and a Winforms Control Library Project (called "Brooklyn"), this is a mock up so there is only a blank form and a single control called MyButton which inherits from windows.forms.button in the control library. This was working fine until the latest VS update to 17.3. Both projects Target NET 6.0

Here's a link to the project on my Google drive. Again it's only a simple mockup to demonstrate the issue.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1r2R_7N5ok0Nk4f96UUOdA3Hzzjc2Jfa1?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. Custom controls in a WinForms app project are listed but those in a library project are not. I can only assume that it's a bug - they're still working on the WinForms designer for .NET Core - so you should report it and hopefully it will be fixed in 17.3.1.

Comment: Note that it is still working as expected for .NET Framework 4.8, so it definitely seems to be a change to the .NET Core WinForms designer that is to blame.

Comment: It was working fine in previous release, version 17.0.13 I believe.

Comment: The previous release was 17.2.6. Sounds like you haven't updated in quite a while. I'm not 100% sure when things changed, as I don't do much WinForms work these days. While testing for questions here and on other sites, I'm fairly sure that I've seen it working some time in 17.2.x. This is probably due to an upgrade in the .NET Core WinForms designer in 17.3 specifically.

Comment: If you think this is the only problem of this update, wait an be amazed

Comment: You're right, it was 17.26 that I had last. So it is a recent problem. Issue is that with community edition you cannot roll back to previous release, only with professional and enterprise. So I guess I'm stuck and can take a vacation while i wait for new release and hopefully it's fixed there.  Thanks

Comment: A 17.3.1 updated has been released to fix some (of the many) issues, but it doesn't solve this one. In case you can use C#, a Class Library or Control Library Project - added to the Solution - that exposes public Controls is immediately acknowledged. A VB.Net assembly has still some problems. Also note that `Option Strict ON` set in the general Options settings is ignored when a new Project is created (set it manually in the new updated Project Properties UI) --  Visual Styles are still off.

Comment: Update 17.3.3 (along with 17.3.2 - 3 updates in 12 days) fixes the issue. Visual Styles are also fixed

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem as well. But I have solved it temporarily by adding existing project to the solution and then visual studio shows all UserControls to ToolBox when I open a Form from another project in same solution.